# MySQL: Fast copy of columns from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

For a database update I want to copy 5 columns from one table to another table in the same MySQL database. Both tables have the same amount of rows, each row has an ID, and the IDs are equal in both tables (so I want to merge these tables). My approach currently is doing this via the following update statement:

```
update table_a, table_b set
   table_a.column1 = table_b.column1,
   table_a.column2 = table_b.column2,
   ...
   where table_a.id = table_b.id
```

I am wondering if there is a faster way to do this as it takes some time for big tables.

Thanks for your help,
Michael

Comment: Both table contain same columns right ? i mean name and number of columns

Comment: @FathahRehmanP Table A has additional columns, all columns from table B should be copied to table A

Comment: if id is indexed in both the tables, then the above query should be faster.

Comment: @thavan thanks for the comment, in fact the ID is already the primary key in both tables

Comment: Please define "*some time*" and "*big tables*" in the final sentence, "*it takes some time for big tables*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how big a difference it will make, but you can try insert-select [On duplicate key ...] instead.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Generally writing data is a slow process. The hard-drive itself is the bottleneck.

Comment: Note that this will only be a viable option in the case where you have a common primary key. But if i read correctly from the comments, you do. This approach is also cleaner to look at, and is especially good for merging two tables into a third.